# Socket com Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, socket.io

Olá, gostaria de pedir ajuda em um projeto que estou fazendo. Gostaria de saber como poderia fazer com que um socket em python "trave" um programa desktop que fiz e só libere esse programa para uso quando o lado do servidor permitir.

Comment: Poderia dar mais informações sobre o que seria "travar o programa"? Como fez esse programa? Como o socket se comunicaria com ele?

Comment: Essa parte da comunicação é parte da dúvida rs Imagine um processo de votação, com um lado servidor (mesário) e o cliente que é a própria urna. O socket seria para "liberar a votação" nesta outra máquina.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a comunicação normal que você tem do programa com o servidor - e coloque no servidor algum request específico para parar de responder aquele cliente se ele não estiver autorizado.

Não é necessário, e nem produtivo, ter um protocolo especial para isso - mesmo por que se o bloqueio fosse do lado do cliente, seu usuário poderia simplesmente editar o programa e apagar esse teste.

O cliente tem que ter uma chave de usuário. O servidor tem que, em cada requisição sabe r aqual cliente está respondendo, e saber, com uma tabela simples no banco de dados, ou qualquer outra estrutura de dados que vocẽ tenha no servidor, se aquele cliente está ativo e tem as permissões para um dado acesso ou não. É o equivalente a estar 'logado' numa sessão, no caso de uma aplicação Web.

De qualquer forma, mesmo que a comunicação do seu cliente com o servidor já seja através de sockets puros (o que seria desnecessário pra começar - é melhor usar um protocolo de mais alto nível pra não ficar reinventando a roda), a lógica de autorização não tem que ficar misturada com a lógica de receber mensagens nos sockets - e sim, na interpretação dessas mensagens.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que por padrão, os sockets são bloqueantes. Isto é, a função que lê os dados que chegam da rede bloqueia a thread atual esperando o dado chegar.

Portanto, caso você não esteja utilizando multithreading no seu cliente, você já tem o que deseja. Quando você chamar a função “read” o programa cliente vai ficar bloqueado aguardando os dados que vem do servidor.

Na verdade é bem mais difícil fazer o contrário, isto é ,sockets não bloqueantes. Fazer o programa continuar executando enquanto aguarda informações da rede é bem mais complexo.